# Abstract Classes / Properties VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, properties, abstract-class

I have an abstract class for a custom user control called `CustomLabel`

```
Private MustInherit Class CustomLabel
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

    'CustomLabels ALWAYS have these controls
    Private _SubLabel As Label
    Private _TextBox As Textbox

    'They also always have these properties, but their val. changes
    Private _LabelSize As Size
    Private _Color As Color
    'etc. etc.

    'getters and setters etc.'

    Public Sub New()

        'when setting up an instance of the child class,
        'I want to perform similar actions in the same order
        ConfigureControlBase()
        ConfigureSubLabel()
        ConfigureTextBox()

        Controls.AddRange(SubLabel, TextBox)

    End Sub
```

The configure methods handle some boilerplate-y stuff like this:

```
Sub ConfigureSubLabel()
    With Me
        .SuspendLayout()
        .BackColor = Color.Transparent
        .TabStop = False
        .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    End With
End Sub
```

within the configures, I had had something like

```
.BackColor = Color
```

the idea being that when you call new, and it in turn goes to configure, it would configure the respective control based on the value of certain properties in the inheriting class.

I have two child classes, `BiggerLabel` and `SmallerLabel`.

`BiggerLabel` itself is larger than `SmallerLabel` (naturally), and all the controls within it also change size in proportion to reflect that. It's color is also different compared to `SmallerLabel`.

Here is where I get confused. In the `new()` constructor for the children, I can say Color = something, but the order the compiler reads the code in makes it not work...for example it sees

```
dim thisLabel as BiggerLabel = new BiggerLabel
```

and goes to the `new()` for `BiggerLabel`, then immediately jumps to the `new()` for `CustomLabel`, configures all the controls based on the default values, and THEN goes back to the child classes `new()` and changes the values of the properties. I end up with Color being the right value in the end, but the .BackColor = Color was set using default values so the control just isn't right even though the underlying data is correct in the end.

From here I came up with a brilliant plan. I gave the parent class a mustinherit `SetProperties()` and placed it before all my configuration stuff, so when it got called the compiler was forced to jump to the inherited version of that sub in the child class, where I would say the size is now = to x and the color = y etc.. This overall seemed unintuitive because I was always setting these same values in the same order, and all child classes had to inherit this class.

My next idea was to make all my base class configures not explicitly change things like size or color, instead only configuring things that are constant. Then I override it in the child, call the base configure which sets up all the data that's always the same (avoiding repetition), and then goes back to the inherited sub to configure things like size and color.

The downside to this is now each inherited sub has to have a call to the base as its first line, and yet again I have to always set the same values in a similar order, which seems really redundant to me.

Basically I want to be able to say "CustomLabel will always have these controls, and they will always be configured this way and this order, but then for BiggerLabel size is w, color is x, and for SmallerLabel size is y, color is z.

So far, I feel like the more I work on this the more confused I get, and verbose google searches regarding abstraction in vb.net or examples of how to abstract properly aren't doing me much good.

Oh yea, and passing args to the abstract new constructor also seems undesirable for me just due to the amount of args I'd be passing.

I also looked into overriding properties, but like I said I'm starting to get burnt out and confused on this, as I'm not to experienced with vb (or coding in general) and I'm not really sure where the compiler is headed without doing extensive debugging and stepping through every inch of my code (which given my two previous iterations, jumps around a lot....making it even MORE confusing!)

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to fight through that wall of text up there and offer a hand. It's probably some really simple solution or coding practice that I missed.

Comment: It seems like you can add an overloaded constructor to accept the default color while initializing. That way you could pass the color in from the children, before the config method is called.

Comment: It would seem you don't need inheritance at all, because your classes only differ in values of their properties, not in behaviour. If you want inheritance anyway, make all three `ConfigureControlBase`, `ConfigureSubLabel`, and `ConfigureTextBox` `MustOverride`, and remove any setup logic from the abstract class.

Comment: The reason for inheritance is twofold. The childclasses have always have the same controls and properties, so the base class sets that up. However, each type of CustomLabel might have additional controls that the base doesn't have, along with certain properties being different.

Comment: Still, `LargeEnhancedCustomLabel` could inherit from `CustomLabel` without `CustomLabel` being abstract

Comment: As for making the configures MustOverride and removing setup logic, the setup logic was there to establish sort of a workflow. These methods where always done in a similar way, in a similar order. For that reason I figured it might be beneficial to have that single piece of code to refer to rather than repeating similar steps in all the children. Then again, maybe I'm just being too anal about not repeating any code.

Comment: @Plutonix , I suppose you are correct in that regard.  I think maybe I just got so deep in the weeds with this that I started going in circles confusing myself.